# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. ao mudar const

Tags: javascript, react

Quero clicar em um TouchableOpacity e mudar o valor da const porém tenho esse erro.

**Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

Código da minha tela:

```
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import theme from '../../constants/theme'

import baixo from '../../assets/images/baixo.png';
import medio from '../../assets/images/medio.png';
import alto from '../../assets/images/alto.png';

import {
    Container,
    MenuButton,
    AddButton,
    TitleText,
    SubtitleText,
    Row,
    Col,
    ImageLevel,
    MinimalText,
    ButtonReport,
    TextButtonReport
} from './styles'


export default function Principal(){
    const [nivel, setNivel] = useState('');<- Quero mudar o valor aqui

    const modalizeAddFlooding = useRef(null);

    openMenu = () =>{
        console.log("openMenu");
    }
  
    const addFlooding = () => {
        modalizeAddFlooding.current?.open();
    };

    const handleNivel = (nivelName) =>{
        setNivel(nivelName);
    }
    

    return (
        <Container>
            <MenuButton
                onPress={openMenu}>
                <Feather
                    name={'menu'}
                    size={30}
                    color= {theme.colors.primary}
                />
            </MenuButton>
            <AddButton
                onPress={addFlooding}>
                <Feather
                    name={'plus'}
                    size={30}
                    color= {theme.colors.white}
                />
            </AddButton>

            <Modalize
                ref={modalizeAddFlooding}
                scrollViewProps={{ showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false }}
                snapPoint={270}
                modalHeight={270}
                handleStyle={{
                    backgroundColor:theme.colors.primaryDark,
                    marginTop:20
                }}
            >
                <TitleText>Relatar alagamento</TitleText>
                <SubtitleText>Nivel da Água</SubtitleText>

                <Row>
                    <Col onPress={handleNivel('baixo')}>
                        <ImageLevel source={baixo}
                        style={ [nivel == 'baixo' && styles.selected]} />
                        <MinimalText>Baixo</MinimalText>
                    </Col>
                    <Col onPress={handleNivel('medio')}>
                        <ImageLevel source={medio}
                        style={ [nivel == 'medio' && styles.selected] }/>
                        <MinimalText>Médio</MinimalText>
                    </Col>
                    <Col onPress={handleNivel('alto')}>
                        <ImageLevel source={alto}
                        style={ [nivel == 'alto' && styles.selected] }/>
                        <MinimalText>Alto</MinimalText>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <ButtonReport>
                        <TextButtonReport>Reportar</TextButtonReport>
                    </ButtonReport>
                </Row>
            </Modalize>

        </Container>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    selected: {
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: theme.colors.text
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A página é renderizada toda vez que ocorre uma alteração de estado, neste caso a função `handleNivel` está sendo executada logo que a página carrega, alterando o estado e fazendo com que a página tenha que ser renderizada novamente e ficando presa em loop.

Se você não fosse atribuir nenhum parâmetro para a função `handleNivel` bastaria colocar o nome dela sem os (parênteses), neste caso, para que você possa utilizar parâmetro e o JS entender que a função só deve ser executada quando ocorrer a ação `onPress`, você deve utilizar uma [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) recebendo o parâmetro e retornando à função `handleNivel`.

Portanto, faça a chamada da `handleNivel` da seguinte forma:

```
onPress ={ ()  => handleNivel(parâmetro) }
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, não sabia dessa regra, tinha pensado que apenas da primeira forma que tinha feito a função já iria ocorrer apenas ao clicar no botão.
**Muito Obrigado!**